# Lyrics: "But they die just the same in your video game"

Tags: lyrics

I have been looking for an answer to this. I am not sure if I can ask this here but I really don't know where else to ask this question. From which artist or song are these lyrics?

"Ain't no kind of glory in killing.
People you can't even see
But they die just the same
In your video game
And the blood on the ground isn't free
No, the blood isn't free"

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.reverbnation.com/rantcaster - Found this, thanks to @Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By googling parts of the lyrics you provided with double quotes I have found [this comment](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/bloombergview/why_drones_stayed_out_of_sight_in_the_2012_campaign/#comment-701520097). Since it's the only result I've got, I'm pretty sure this must be the song you're looking for.

I haven't found the song anywhere and I don't know if the alias in the above comment actually is his artist name. But if it is, the song you're looking for is **"Predator" by *Rantcaster***.

Comment: Thank you for finding it for me. I wish this person's song was online!

Comment: I also found the lyrics in the comments section on this article - the artist's name is likely William L. Valenti. http://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/jun/17/former-us-military-personnel-letter-us-drone-pilots